# How to resolve promises of child controller on route change?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework, angular-promise

I have an Angular Ionic app. I assigned controller, template and its resolve promises in its routes. This is working fine so that my main controller only loads after all the promises of parent controller resolved.
But if this route contains another child controller with some promises. Here the problem is the page only need to load after all the promises of parent and child controller resolved.

[Punker](http://plnkr.co/edit/G5VJd289KprS92hs3uCT)

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ionic']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
      url: "/dashboard",
      templateUrl: "dashboard.html",
      controller: 'DashboardController',
      title: 'Dashboard',
      resolve: {
          UserDetails: function(DataService) {
              return DataService.getUserDetails(1);
          },
          DashboardDetails: function(DataService) {
              return DataService.getDashboardDetails();
          }
      }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');
});

app.factory('DataService', function($q) {
   return {
     getUserDetails: function(id){
       var defer = $q.defer();
       var userDetails = {
         name: "Saidh"
       }
       defer.resolve(userDetails);
       return defer.promise;
     },
     getDashboardDetails: function(){
       var defer = $q.defer();
       var dashboardDetails = {
         title: "Dashboard"
       }
       defer.resolve(dashboardDetails);
       return defer.promise;
     }
   }
});

app.controller('HeaderController', function($scope, UserDetails) {
   console.log(UserDetails);//Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
   $scope.userDetails = UserDetails;
});
app.controller('DashboardController', function($scope, DashboardDetails) {
   console.log(DashboardDetails);//Working: show result
   $scope.dashboardDetails = DashboardDetails;
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple add **nested** states, and each state should have it's own `resolve: somePromise` attribute, [here i fork your plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KxBmcr?p=preview) and add a timeout so the parent and children view are only shown when the `promise` is `solved`

Example:

```
    $stateProvider.state('header', {
      url: "/home",
      templateUrl: "header.html",
      controller: 'HeaderController',
      resolve: {
          UserDetails: function(DataService) {
              return DataService.getUserDetails(1);
          }
      }
  });

  $stateProvider.state('header.dashboard', {
      url: "/dashboard",
      controller: 'DashboardController',
      templateUrl: "dashboard.html",
      parent: 'header',
      resolve: {
          DashboardDetails: function(DataService) {
              return DataService.getDashboardDetails();
          }
      }
  });
```

That way it's very strategist-forward

Comment: This solution solve the issue, but the URL strict to use a header/ for all the routes having header :(.

Comment: No no, the only thing you have to do is set :   **url: "/"**. It's a valid url. However i think would be a better experience if change the Header into a Directive inside a _home state_ in this home state handle the basic user info/login, and add a _Loading overlay_ until the promise is solved, then redirect using **$state.go(´dashboard')**. Please remember to select which is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You could get the resolve promises inside `DashboardController` only, You will never get it inside home controller which is inside the html template.
The resolve services are available inside the controller which are mentioned on route `state` itself. So as you can access the dependency inside `DashboardController` place it in scope variable & make it available to child scopes and view too.

Also you need to remove `UserDetails` dependency from `HomeController` to get rid of error, because `UserDetails` will never accessible there

**Code**

```
app.controller('DashboardController', function($scope, DashboardDetails, UserDetails) {
  console.log(UserDetails); //Working: show result
  $scope.dashboardDetails = DashboardDetails;
  $scope.userDetails = UserDetails;
});
```

See [**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/GThQOwzVLXQOhND8xBS4?p=preview) Here

Comment: Currently I used like this. But I like to define scope variables of a template in its on controller ;).